# How to properly add notifications_rule in budget according to budgets_v1 library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The code below is deployed on Google Cloud Platform as Cloud Function and it work just fine without notifications_rule part:

```
'notifications_rule': {
                'pubsub_topic': 'projects/######/topics/######'
            }
```

This is the full codes with that notifications_rule part in it

```
import google.auth
from google.cloud.billing import budgets_v1 as budget_service
from google.cloud import billing_v1 as billing_service

def create_budgets(data, context):
    budget_client = budget_service.BudgetServiceClient()
    billing_client = billing_service.CloudBillingClient()

    # Set the billing account ID and budget amount
    request = billing_service.ListProjectBillingInfoRequest(
        name="billingAccounts/###################",
    )

    print(f"billing_id:{request.name}")

    page_result = billing_client.list_project_billing_info(request=request)

    # List the projects under the billing account
    projects = []
    for project in page_result:
        projects.append(project)

    # Create the budget for each project
    for project_id in projects:
        print(f"project name:{project_id.name}")
        project_name = project_id.name.split('/')[1]
        budget = {
            'display_name': f'{project_name} cost 10% more than last month',
            'budget_filter': {
                'projects': [f'projects/{project_id.project_id}']
            },
            'amount': {
                'last_period_amount': {}
            },
            'notifications_rule': {
                'pubsub_topic': 'projects/######/topics/######'
            },
            'threshold_rules': [
                {
                    'threshold_percent': 1.1,
                    'spend_basis': 'CURRENT_SPEND',
                },
                {
                    'threshold_percent': 1.1,
                    'spend_basis': 'FORECASTED_SPEND',
                }
            ]
        }
        print(f"budgets:{budget}")

        # Create the budget request
        parent = f'{request.name}'

        # Create the budget and print the result
        #response = budget_client.create_budget(budget_request=budget_request)
        response = budget_client.create_budget(parent=parent, budget=budget)
        print(f'Budget created for project {project_id}: {response.name}')
```

requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-billing>=1.10.0
google-cloud-billing-budgets==1.11.0
google-auth>=2.17.0
```

Please help me~

I've tried remove the notifications_rule and it work just fine, but when I add that part into the code error 400 Invalid schema showed up